# Hello i am using Quickblox API to chat in my application. But i have issue related password length

Tags: ios, authentication, passwords, quickblox

Hello i am using Quickblox API to chat in my application.
But i have issue related password length.

I want to set minimum password length 5.
By default its minimum length is 8. 
Is it possible to set password length 5 with Quickblox in ios?
And if possible then give me right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, min password length is 8.

If you need 5 - you can add 3 extra characters, for example

```
NSString *password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pwd%@", realUserPassword];
```

Comment: but i need to decrease the password length.