# Quickblox User registration Password Limit Error IOS

Tags: ios, passwords, limit, quickblox

Currently when i am registering a new user to Quickblox Server Then i am getting this below error

```
 "password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)"
```

Is there any property where i can set the minimum Password limit?

Or in Quickblox Web admin settings i can set any property.

Actually i want to set minimum password limit to 7. But from quickblox the password limit is 8.

I have tried researching regarding it but could not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [igor-khomenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574475/igor-khomenko)'s Answer

[hello-i-am-using-quickblox-api-to-chat-in-my-application-but-i-have-issue-relat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673501/hello-i-am-using-quickblox-api-to-chat-in-my-application-but-i-have-issue-relat)

> Actually by default , min password length is 8.
>
> If you need 5 - you can add 3 extra characters, for example
>
> ```
> NSString *password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pwd%@", realUserPassword];
> ```

Comment: Does not making sense in response to my question regarding Quickblox?

Comment: I think there is no property for set minimum password length. so , if you want to set length then you have to use otherway like this.

Comment: Sorry for the above comment. It will work. Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: It's ok . Happy to Help.